# How do I Indicate an Error in a TypeConverter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, error-handling, model-binding, typeconverter

I'm trying to do some [model binding on simple types with `TypeConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding#model-binding-review) in ASP.NET Core 2, i.e. converting a `string` to my custom type.

If the string has the wrong format, I would like to indicate it, e.g. by throwing an exception:

```cs
public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
{
    if (value is string s)
    {
        var result = Parse(s);

        if (!result.Success)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid format", nameof(value), result.Exception);
        }

        return result.Value;

    }

    return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
}
```

It currently seems like the exception is simply swallowed and ignored, leaving the bound value the default value.
The caller of the endpoint is never told that the value is wrong, nor does my code in the controller know that the value was originally invalid (the default value could easily be a valid value).

I wish the conversion to fail hard, if the format is invalid, but how do I do that?

Comment: You should be using validation instead of a type converter to validate data. Exceptions are, for lack of a better word, exceptional and you should avoid them except when you can't possibly continue. If you just want to tell the user "this isn't right", use validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The caller of the endpoint is never told that the value is wrong, nor
>   does my code in the controller know that the value was originally
>   invalid (the default value could easily be a valid value).

All model binding errors are communicated via `ControllerBase.ModelState` property accessible in controller actions. `ModelState` has `IsValid` property set to `false` if some error happens during model [binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding) or [validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation).

It's an intended separation of concerns. Such approach has following advantages comparing to exception bubbling as you want:

- All binding and validation errors for all action parameters will be available altogether in `ModelState`. With exception approach only the first met error will be communicated.
- Exception will break request pipeline execution. With `ModelState` you could take appropriate actions on later pipeline stages and decide whether the request still could be processed with encountered errors.
- `ModelState` approach is much more flexible in error handling. You could return appropriate response (e.g. `400 Bad Request` or return HTML view with detailed error description).

The most basic approach for handling invalid model state is through thin Action Filter that checks `ModelState.IsValid` value:

```
public class CheckModelStateAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

Registering the filter in `Startup.ConfigureServices():`

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new CheckModelStateAttribute());
});
```

In the case of model binding error, HTTP error code `400 Bad Request` will be returned to the caller with , controller action will not be invoked.

[**Sample Project on GitHub**](https://github.com/CodeFuller/stackoverflow/tree/Q49696060-Error-In-TypeConverter)

Comment: Although keeping type conversion and validation separate leads to better organized code, it requires us to parse the input twice, which can lead to slower code. I have a large (non-JSON) string that I want to convert to an object. It needs to be parsed and each part needs to be validated. I am now calling the function for parsing twice, once in the validation and once again in the type converter which started showing performance impact, so I eventually just started doing everything inside the controller where I can return 400 if parsing fails.